# Same record is being inserted twice

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

At first the same record was inserted 6 times, but now it is inserted twice, and I haven't changed a thing. Anyway, I only want it to be inserted only one time. My code looks like this:

```
public class DBLogic
    {
    internal bool RegisterNewUser(string uName, string email, string password)
        {            
            if (EmailAlreadyExists(email))
            {
                return false;
            }

            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime dateOfReg = today; // today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            using (_msqlCon = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                _msqlCon.Open();

                _query = "INSERT INTO RegisteredUsers (Username, Email, Password, DateOfRegistration) VALUES (?uName, ?email, ?password, ?dateOfReg)";
                _command = new MySqlCommand(_query, _msqlCon);

                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("uName", uName);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", email);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", password);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateOfReg", dateOfReg);

                _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            return true;
        }
}
```

In the begining I wasn't using the `using` statement, and then it seemed to work fine. Though I am not sure that it is the `using` statement that has the guilt here. Can you see any problems in my code that might cause it?

The code that starts the call is the Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(RegisteredUsersModel registerUserModel)
    {
        ViewBag.Header = "Register";
        string msg = "";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!registerUserModel.RegisterUser(registerUserModel.nickName, registerUserModel.email, registerUserModel.password))
            {
                msg = "The provided email already exists";
            }

            ViewBag.DeniedMsg = msg;
            return PartialView("_Register");
        }

        return PartialView("_Register");
    }
```

And the action method sends it on to the Model:

```
    namespace WebApplication1.Models
   {
    public RegisteredUsersModel()
        {
            logic = new DBLogic();
        }

    public bool RegisterUser(string uName, string email, string password)
        {
            return logic.RegisterNewUser(uName, email, password);
        }
   }
```

The logic class is the one above that inserts in the database
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hard to tell from your code, but it looks like both the action and the model seem to be calling the same method?

Comment: Yes, but users is defined as users = new Models.RegisteredUsersModel();

They are calling a method that has same name, but in different classes

Comment: We can't see from the above where the model is instantiated, or where 'logic' is declared.  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: I've added more details now

Comment: OK, you've still not show how your 'action method sends it on to the logic', but both your controller and your model class seem to call a method called RegisterUser on the DBLogic class.  Are you *sure* this isn't your problem?